# Scheduled XOTS tasklet produces exception (OpenNTF Domino API)

Tags: xpages

Maybe I don't understand this right, but it's not documented with a sample, so I had to play with it. I created a class that will be used as a XOTS tasklet:

```
package org.sutol.demo.xots;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.openntf.domino.xots.Tasklet;
import org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogUtil;

@Tasklet(session = Tasklet.Session.CLONE, schedule = "cron:0 */1 00-23 * * *")
public class PeriodicTask implements Callable<String> {

    public String call() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
        String result = "Message from PeriodicTask: " + formatter.format(now.getTime());
        createOutput(result);
        return result;
    }

    private void createOutput(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent(null, msg, Level.INFO, null);
    }

}
```

This class is used when I use the schedule method of the Xots object:

```
public static void testPeriodicTasklet() {
    Xots.getService().schedule(new PeriodicTask(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

There are a couple of problems here:

- the tasklet is executed only once, not every second as I determined
- I get an error message on the server console

Error message on server console:

```
08.11.2015 18:59:39   HTTP JVM: ### LOGSTART
08.11.2015 18:59:39   HTTP JVM: Message from PeriodicTask: 08.11.2015, 18:59:39
08.11.2015 18:59:39   HTTP JVM: INIT
08.11.2015 18:59:39   [ODA::WARNING] null
08.11.2015 18:59:39   [ODA::WARNING]    (source:org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils$4.run - See IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\org.openntf.log.X.Y.txt for full stack trace.)
08.11.2015 18:59:39   HTTP JVM: ### LOGSUCCESS
```

This is the content of the log file:

```
2015-11-08T18:59:39 [WARNING]: com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.resolveVariable - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.resolveVariable(FacesUtil.java:1048)
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.getXSPContext(XSPContext.java:59)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.getXspContext(ExtLibUtil.java:202)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogItem.setThisAgent(XspOpenLogItem.java:132)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogItem.getThisAgent(XspOpenLogItem.java:124)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogItem.writeToLog(XspOpenLogItem.java:419)
    at org.openntf.domino.logging.BaseOpenLogItem.logEvent(BaseOpenLogItem.java:685)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent(XspOpenLogUtil.java:134)
    at org.sutol.demo.xots.PeriodicTask.createOutput(PeriodicTask.java:24)
    at org.sutol.demo.xots.PeriodicTask.call(PeriodicTask.java:18)
    at org.sutol.demo.xots.PeriodicTask.call(PeriodicTask.java:1)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.xots.XotsWrappedTask.invokeObject(XotsWrappedTask.java:145)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.xots.XotsWrappedTask.invokeTasklet(XotsWrappedTask.java:125)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.xots.XotsWrappedTask.callOrRun(XotsWrappedTask.java:55)
    at org.openntf.domino.xsp.xots.XotsDominoExecutor$XotsWrappedCallable.call(XotsDominoExecutor.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at org.openntf.domino.thread.AbstractDominoExecutor$DominoFutureTask.run(AbstractDominoExecutor.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:384)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:580)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:767)
```

Can someone tell me a better sample or what I am doing wrong here?
I'd like to click a button to start the periodic task (and of course I want to stop then with another button click, but this isn't something I figured out how to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the call to XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent
It's not available in Xots context

Comment: That resolves the problem with the exception. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 1):

XspContext is not available in Xots. All the XPages-related elements, like the VariableResolver used by resolveVariable would need instantiating somehow. The further complication is that they would need instantiating with the same ClassLoader as the XPages runtime, otherwise they would be a separate instance of the XPages elements, so applicationScope would be a separate applicationScope, not subsequently accessible from an XPage. I tend to pass in any XPages-runtime objects and have my utility methods use try/catch to go to the XPages runtime, otherwise the relevant property of the Xots task.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I got trapped.
When I auto completed the schedule method of the Xots class I incidentally used the wrong method. It was a method from `java.util.concurrent` and not from `org.openntf.domino.thread`

I changed to the correct method which needs a PeriodicScheduler like this one:

```
public static void startPeriodicTasklet() {
        PeriodicScheduler sched = new PeriodicScheduler(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Xots.getService().schedule(new PeriodicTask(), sched);
}
```

With this method the code is executed every second. Now I only have to figure out how to stop that :-D